# Form control using col-md-6 spacing when viewport minimised with bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am moving a form i wrote in bootstrap 2 across to responsive bootstrap 3.

When the large grid is displayed there is nice spacing between all elements. The below works OK for large viewports:

[image: large viewport]

When the viewport is minimized and small grid media selected, the firstName and lastName wrap as intended, but it looks ugly as there is no space between these two rows (like there is for the emailAddress and companyName):

[image]

How can i make equal spacing between all elements the same between both small and large grids, and specifically target the height between `col-sm-12` items within a `form-group` (as we have with firstName and lastName)?

My code is below and **[jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/bpbDF/)**:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="control-label">Billing Contact</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><input id="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'First Name' }" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><input id="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'Last Name' }" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12"><input id="emailAddress" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: emailAddress, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'E-mail Address' }" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12"><input id="companyName" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: companyName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'Company Name' }" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="control-label">Billing Address</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12"><input id="address1" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: address1, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'Street Address' }" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think there's a Bootstrap class you can use for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CSS and Media Queries:

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
{    
    .form-group .col-sm-12:first-child{margin-bottom:15px;} 
}
```

Comment: Media query worked, I ended up using: `@media (max-width: 991px){ .form-group .col-xs-12{margin-bottom:15px;} .form-group .col-xs-12:last-child{margin-bottom:0;} } `

One minor question though, instead of using absolute 991px, is there not a less variable for this grid that i could reference instead?

Comment: @screen-sm-max is 991px in variables.less

Answer (score 4):

Is there a particular reason why you don't want to add margin yourself? Because you can target all of the columns with a simple css selector if you give your `form-group` an id to select with more accuracy. Below is the snippet and you can check the **[result](http://cdpn.io/hmktd)** and online **[snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hmktd)** as well.

**HTML**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" id="main-form">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-form > [class^="col-"] { /* This will grab all the elements with classes that start with "col-" and that are the immediate children of #main-form. */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    /* or the value of your bootstrap's gutter width so that you can have a nice consistent margin between elements*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for me is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><input id="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'First Name' }" /></div>
    <div class="clearfix mb-1 hidden-md-up"></div> <!-- this block -->
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><input id="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: 'Last Name' }" /></div>
</div>
```

The trick is to whistle up a margin between inputs just when both change to full width.